# How to find the nth number in a sequence with 'limited digits'

Tags: sequences-and-series

Imagine a list of decreasing 4 digits numbers using every digit 3 to 0 exactly once. (So total 24 possibilities because 4!  = 24)
My question is. How mathematically can I figure out the nth term. Also this is a scaled down version. I would need something with 11 digits.
Thank you.

Comment: You mean something as the millionth permutation with $11$ elements, if they are sorted lexicographically ?

Comment: Exactly that! Just not specifically the millionth

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind I'll do this in increasing order. It just makes the expressions simpler that way. Same arguments work for decreasing, or you can just subtract the index you want from $11!$.

Let's work with $r$ symbols, rather than just $11$. We wish to calculate 
$$
(x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{r-1})
$$
for the $n$-th term in the sequence.

The basic observation is this:

The first $(r-1)!$ patterns start with $0$.

The next $(r-1)!$ patterns start with $1$.

and so on...

So to calculate the first value in the pattern at position $n$, simply take
$$
x_0 = \left\lfloor {n\over (r-1)!} \right\rfloor
$$
Now set 
$$
n_1 = n - x_0 (r-1)!
$$
and repeat for finding the $n_1$-th value from a sorted list of $r-1$ symbols. Except you have to be careful not to repeat the value you've already chosen for $x_0$. And so on...

This all looks a bit messy, and actually it's easier to ignore the symbols you've chosen and fix it up at the end.

So the 'proper' solution is to build a sequence $(y_i)_{i=0}^{r-1}$ as follows.

Let $n_0 = n$

Then
$$
y_i = \left\lfloor {n_i\over (r-1-i)!} \right\rfloor
$$
$$
n_{i+1} = n_i - y_i (r-1-i)!
$$
for $i$ from $0$ to $r-1$.

To construct $(x_i)$, simply take the $y_i$ values to be the index (counting $0$-up) into the set of values yet to be chosen.

Here's an example using base $11$. I'll use symbols $A$ through $K$ in place of digits. Suppose we want to find the sequence numbered $31419920$.

Each choice of the first symbol has $10! = 3628800$ sequences associated with it.
$$
31419920 / 3628800 = 8 = y_0
$$
The remainder is 
$$
31419920 - 8*3628800 = 2389520
$$
Each choice of the next symbol has $9! = 362880$ sequences associated with it.
$$
2389520 / 362880 = 6 = y_1
$$
The remainder is 
$$
2389520 - 6*362880 = 212240
$$
Continuing this pattern
$$
212240 / 8! = 212240 / 40320 = 5 \text{ remainder } 10640
$$
$$
10640 / 7! = 10640 / 5040 = 2 \text{ remainder }560
$$
$$
560 / 6! = 560 / 720 = 0 \text{ remainder }560
$$
$$
560 / 5! = 560 / 120 = 4 \text{ remainder }80
$$
$$
80 / 4! = 80 / 24 = 3 \text{ remainder }8
$$
$$
8 / 3! = 8 / 6 = 1 \text{ remainder }2
$$
$$
2 / 2! = 2 / 2 = 1 \text{ remainder }0
$$
The resulting sequence $(y_i)$ is 
$$
(8,6,5,2,0,4,3,1,1,0,0)
$$
Now convert this to the symbols.

The $8$th symbol is $I$ ($A = 0$). $ABCDEFGHJK$ remain.

The $6$th symbol is $G$. $ABCDEFHJK$ remain.

The $5$th symbol is $F$. $ABCDEHJK$ remain.

The $2$nd symbol is $C$. $ABDEHJK$ remain.

The $0$th symbols is $A$. $BDEHJK$ remain.

The $4$th symbol is $J$. $BDEHK$ remain.

The $3$rd symbol is $H$. $BDEK$ remain.

The $1$st symbol is $D$. $BEK$ remain.

The $1$st symbol is $E$. $BK$ remain.

The $0$th symbol is $B$. $K$ remains.

So the sequence is $IGFCAJHDEBK$.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, but I'm a sophomore and I have no clue what half of this means :(   any simpler way to explain?  Sorry :/

Comment: Also in the final thingy I won't be using base 10

Comment: I'll add an example base 11 to my answer. That may help.

Comment: Thank you so much. The example was so much easier to understand than the formulas. Using it I made a spreadsheet to do all the calculations. I appreciated your help!